# Arch Linux KDE Plasma Black Screen after login

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma

I wanted to install kde plasma, so I followed the next steps:

```
pacman -S xorg-server xorg-apps xorg-xinit xterm
pacman -S xf86-video-nouveau
pacman -S plasma-meta kde-applications-meta
pacman -S sddm
systemctl start sddm.service
```

But when i run `systemctl start sddm.service` to start KDE plasma in the login screen doesn't apper the mouse but it's there because I can move the profile the mouse seems invisible on the other hand when I type the password and enter I have a black screen but this time I can see the mouse.

[image]
[image]
How i can solve it?

Btw i installed gdm and works why kde plasma not??

Thx.

Comment: (I've never run Arch+KDE in VirtualBox, I may be not aware of well known issues). Have you tried switching to a different tty (sending e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F2 to the VM) and querying the logs (`journalctl`)?

Comment: ...and/or Xorg's logs in `/var/log`.

Answer (score 0):

Install VirtualBox Guest Packages - `virtualbox-guest-utils` and `xf86-video-vmware`.
It may also be needed - `virtualbox-guest-dkms`.

And also load VBox modules in the system - `modprobe -a vboxguest vboxsf vboxvideo`

Read more here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox/Install_Arch_Linux_as_a_guest#Install_the_Guest_Additions

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox/Install_Arch_Linux_as_a_guest#Load_the_VirtualBox_kernel_modules

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this resolves the OP's issue (as I had mouse control even at the login screen and they noted not having the issue using GDE), but this simple fix resolved my similar issue anyway (black screen after login).

I realized I hadn't setup a user home directory, or had set /home as the user home directory.

Therefore, setting up a user-owned home directory and then restarting resolved the issue for me. Either simply by `useradd -d $user` (note the -d), or manually creating a new user directory, transferring ownership, and then setting the user home directory setting:

```
cd /home
mkdir $user
chown $user:$group ./$user
usermod -d /home/$user $user
```

After a reboot, I was able to get a successful login

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a kernel package newer than 5.6, install `virtualbox-guest-utils`, if you're using 5.6 or older, you need to install `virtualbox-guest-dkms`, along with the headers needed for your kernel.

Then, you need to enable and start `vboxservice.service`.

You do not need `xf86-video-nouveau`.